# Right Way for changing timeoutIntervalForRequest in Alamofire

Tags: ios, alamofire, nsurlsession

I changed **timeoutIntervalForRequest** with

```
let manager = Alamofire.SessionManager.default
manager.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 3    
manager.request(url).response {}
```

but seems not worked, Any suggestion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This worked for me :)

```
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = TimeInterval(7)
configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = TimeInterval(7)
let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration)

let task = session.dataTask(with: url) {}
```

Changes to the configuration of an already initialized URLSession have no effect, per Apple's documentation. If you want a custom timeout, either set the value on your requests, or create a custom URLSession with a custom configuration, as outlined in [document](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#session-manager)

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like:

```
lazy var alamofireSession : Alamofire.SessionManager = { [weak self] in
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = TimeInterval(30)
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = TimeInterval(30)
    let session = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration, delegate: sessionDelegate, serverTrustPolicyManager: nil)   
    return session
}()
```

Answer (score 1):

For swift3 try this

```
  var alamoManager: SessionManager?
    //Mark -- Alamofire session manager
                let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
                configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 3
                alamoManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
alamoManager.request(request).responseJSON {
                        response in

            }
```

Also this is one option

```
Alamofire.SessionManager.default.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 300
```

Comment: opt1 return  `Error: Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" `     opt2 does not work(the timeoutInterval seems still the default value 60)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL.init(string: "URL")! as URL)
request.timeoutInterval = 3
    // do additional configuration with your request like pass header etc....
Alamofire.request(request as! URLRequestConvertible).responseJSON {
        response in
        // do whatever you want here
    }
```

Comment: It couldn't compile in Swift3, Swift3 please

Comment: try now ... you need to set header body if server side validation exist .